# Python3 - Replacing spaces with underscore, but skip first element

Tags: python

I have a file with names with spaces. I am trying to make files for each of the names in the file, only using their last names. Here is an example of the file:

```
Ernest Hemingway
Mark Twain
Ralph Waldo Emerson 
Edgar Allan Poe
Robert Frost
```

The files created should be in the format of:

```
Hemingway.txt
Twain.txt
Waldo_Emerson.txt
Allan_Poe.txt
```

Where the spaces in the last names are replaced by underscores. I am having trouble with getting rid of the first names when replacing the spaces. This is what I have so far:

```
file_name=name.replace(" ", "_")
```

I'm not sure how to somehow ignore the first "element" when it replaces. The other thing I thought about doing is to use split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just mix this replace with a substing:

```
my_string="Ralph Waldo Emerson"
my_string.split(" ",1)[1].replace(" ", "_")
```

This should do the trick.
I hope it helps.
BR

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def get_last_name(name):
    return "_".join(name.split()[1:])
```

`split()` splits the string into tokens (separated at whitespaces), and `[1:]` selects all but the first element of the split. We then join those elements together with an underscore `"_"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) along with further slicing to generate a list with the specified output structure:

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('my_file.txt')]
['_'.join(i.split()[1:]) + '.txt' for i in lines]
```

**Output**

```
['Hemingway.txt',
 'Twain.txt',
 'Waldo_Emerson.txt',
 'Allan_Poe.txt',
 'Frost.txt']
```

Comment: More complete than my answer, +1. I think you do not need the `rstrip`, though, you can just iterate the lines. So it could be `['_'.join(i.split()[1:]) + '.txt' for i in open("my_file.txt")]`.

Comment: Thans @JanChristophTerasa, yours is complete enough though returned :)

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner using list comprehension, where we ignore the first word, and join all other words in the string with an underscore

```
li = [ '_'.join(item.split()[1:])+'.txt'  for item in open('file.txt')]
print(li)
```

So if the file.txt is

```
Ernest Hemingway
Mark Twain
Ralph Waldo Emerson 
Edgar Allan Poe
Robert Frost
```

The output will be

```
['Hemingway.txt', 'Twain.txt', 'Waldo_Emerson.txt', 'Allan_Poe.txt', 'Frost.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
name_list = ["Ernest Hemingway","Ralph Waldo Emerson"]
filenames = []
for name in names:
    filenames += ["_".join(name.split(" ")[1:]) + ".txt"]
```